# Implementing good equals method

Tags: java, coding-style

Say I want to create a new class called **Foo** in Java, and it has 2 member variables, **int bar** and **double temp**, and I want to give that class an equals method that compares 2 instances of the class and returns a boolean value. I have 2 instances of Foo, f1 and f2. Assuming the constructor is properly defined, many people would tell me to do this:

```
public boolean equals(Foo f2)
{
    return (bar  == f2.getBar() && 
            temp == f2.getTemp());
}
```

where to check for equality, you would do

```
f1.equals(f2);
```

However, I'm pretty sure I've seen some people do this instead:

```
public static boolean equals(Foo f1, Foo f2)
{
    return (f1.getBar()  == f2.getBar() && 
            f1.getTemp() == f2.getTemp());
}
```

where to check for equality, you would do

```
Foo.equals(f1, f2);
```

My question was that since I've seen both implementations, which one of the two is considered better programming style?

Comment: This isn't a great question because it's asking for opinion. Neither are "better" if they both work however the Java lang convention is clearly the first. The important thing is you satisfy the [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using the non static version, because this overrides the Object.equals method, which java will call at times you're not aware, such as when your Foo object is inside a collection, and you call myList.contains(myfooInstance). If you only implement the static version, it won't get called when java needs to know if two Foo objects are equal. But as Phesmo states, you need to use the 'Object' parameter instead of a 'Foo' parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Standard Java classes like `HashMap` is expecting method like

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
//                    ^^^^^^
```

not

```
public boolean equals(Foo f2)
```

which means it will use `equals(Object obj)` inherited from your superclass (so if superclass is Object it will end up using `==` internally).

So both methods are simply additional methods which may be equally good or equally bad depending on how you want to use them. IMO `equals(Foo f2)` is slightly worse because it causes confusion with `equals(Object o)`.

Answer (score 0):

The two code snippets represent different implementations and will be used to serve different purposes.

```
public boolean equals(Foo f2)
{
    return (bar  == f2.getBar() && 
            temp == f2.getTemp());
}
```

That snippet is to implement in `Foo` class where it checks against another `Foo`.

Where as

```
public static boolean equals(Foo f1, Foo f2)
{
    return (f1.getBar()  == f2.getBar() && 
            f1.getTemp() == f2.getTemp());
}
```

Is a util where you pass, two `Foo's` for check `equality`.